# How could i deselect checkbox?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

For pincode I tried this:

```
checkbox = webdriver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@name="add_in_fld"].onclick()')
            if checkbox.isSelected():
                    checkbox.click()
```

**[Sample Link](http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/batch-geocode/#.VbsHL7OqpHz)**

Comment: Can you please add a sample URL.

Comment: http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/batch-geocode/#.VbsHL7OqpHz.. if i just want to see the lat nd lng.. nt the address

Comment: Any error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/batch-geocode/#.VbsHL7OqpHz")
cb = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".cb_short input")
assert cb.is_selected()
cb.click()
assert not cb.is_selected()
```